# How to Move the Position of an Image from Grid Box to Grid Box

Tags: java, grid-layout

I need to know how to move my checker piece from square to square using a GridLayout. I have the GridLayout created, I will post the code for it underneath. I haven't actually made the checker piece yet, but I just need to know how to move an image from box to box by clicking on a box. My class is called GridLayout, if that is needed.

GridLayout Code:

```
public static void main(String args){

GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(8, 8, 57.25, 57.25);

}


public GridLayout(int row, int cols, double hgap, double vgap) {
    super();
    this.row = row;
    this.cols = cols;
    this.hgap = hgap;
    this.vgap = vgap;
}
```

Snippet:

```
public Frame(){

    //I cut out the beginning part that included adding the buttons to the top of the Frame, but this was the constructor.

public static void main(String args[]){
    ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("checkerboard.jpg"); 
    JLabel bg = new JLabel();
    bg.setIcon(icon1);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setTitle("Checkers");
    frame.setSize(414, 474);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frame.add(bg);
    frame.setLocale(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
}

//I also cut out a changeSize() method that was activated when the start button was pressed.

}
```

Comment: Your code shows how you initialize a grid (don't pick the same name as the JDK class), but you're talking about a piece you didn't even create. What components are in the grid? What ideas did you have fro trying to move the piece?

Comment: Well, I have a class called Frame that basically sets up the frame and sets the background image. What I want to do now is put a GridLayout on top of that and have the ability to click on one box that contains a checkers piece, and then click on another box to move it there.

Comment: Post a code snippet (not your whole program) that we can run, make sure it compiles for us, and that demonstrates your problem. "*click on one box that contains a checkers piece*" we don't know what a "box" is.

Comment: alright, I just added it, the checkerboard.jpg is just an image of a checkerboard

Comment: Alright, I see. You're taking the wrong approach for creating your board. Instead of a static image, you will want to add `JLabels` (or `JPanel`s) to your grid and color them, That will give you an interactive board. Then you can assign pieces to those components when needed.

Comment: Alright, so I'm gonna need to set an icon or a background color for each JLabel/JPanel? Then I'll make a MouseEvent or something so when one of the JLabels/JPanels are clicked they perform the "move" function?

Comment: Exactly! You will loop on the 8x8 grid and color the component accordingly (think about the condition that will give the same color for every other square). You can add the pieces (set the icon of paint the image) and add the mouse listener in the same loop. You can post your code by editing your question if you need help with it.